# using file scope variables in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Beginner question

Running on server side, in node.js:

If I use a file-scope (or even global) variable which is set by an export.function(), where that exported function is called via ajax from a client, if multiple requests come from different clients, is the variable now prone to unexpected results?

I.e. do I need to set up an array so every time the export.function() is called it adds a new file-scope instance for that particular ajax request?  Or is this magically handled by node.js where every ajax request gets its own instance of the server?

Answer (score 1):

Requests will share the same instances so you'll need to guard against this.  Note, however, that blocks of synchronous code will be executed completely before execution switches to handle another request so this simplifies the "guarding" you need to do.

Comment: thanks!  I am using these globals across asynchronous posts/responses so it sounds like it will need to address it.

Comment: so to clarify, it seems the standard way to fix this is to append globals to the req.  For example:

exports.server_route( req, res )  {

    req.globals={ g1:0, g2:"init", g3:0 };
    somefuncwithpassedcallback( function ( req, res ) {
         // access globals via req.globals.g1, etc
    } );
}

function somefuncwithpassedcallback( callback ) {

   callback( req, res );
}

and then ALWAYS call everything including the req and res in the argument list (req to access request and appended globals, and res to generate a response if failures or the normal response nested in some callback).